# Data visualization with R: sentiment analysis

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a data frame looks like the following,

```
text                 class.negative        class.positive       class
<fctr>                    <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>

firmly believe...       11                   24                   3
when i thought...       3                    3                    4
fans of david...        11                   24                   12
just watched...         3                    5                    9
i was so looking...     16                   9                    10
```

I would like to visualize the result and just start learning how to work with ggplot, and show "positive", "negative" and "total scores". But obviously I can't simply put them as

```
ggplot(data=..., aes(x=..., y=..., fill=...)) + geom_bar(stat="identity",position = 'stack') + ggtitle('Sentimental Analysis')
```

I wonder how I can create a similar chart like this http://joxi.ru/vAWvKx5HeXp72W, any tips/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try using the `reshape2` package, melt your data first: `dfm <- melt(df, id.vars = 'text')`, then plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to reshape your data first and then use [`geom_line`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_line.html) from `ggplot`. I will use [`gather`](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/gather.html) from `tidyr` for the reshaping of your data. I am calling the starting data_frame `dff`.

```
dff %>% gather(opinion, values, -text) %>%
    ggplot(data = .) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = text, y = values, group = opinion, color = opinion))
```

This should yield:

[image]

You can also visualize the data using [`geom_bar`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) with the following:

```
dff %>% 
    gather(opinion, values, -text) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(y = values, x = text, fill = opinion), stat = "identity")
```

It should yield something like:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: You're a life saver! That's exactly what I was trying to do, I was wondering if its possible to use `geom_bar` ? Since I have lots of datas, the lines kind of get messy in between. Many thanks!!