# Visualizing sentiment over time with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, lubridate

I am trying to visualize sentiment over time similar to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41274935/data-visualization-with-r-sentiment-analysis).

My dataset looks as follows:

```
head(Visualizing_sentiment)
```

```
date
<S3: POSIXct>
sentiment
<chr>
2011-12-01  neutral         
2011-12-01  negative            
2011-12-01  negative            
2011-12-01  negative            
2011-12-01  negative            
2011-12-01  negative
```

I ran the following for visualization:

```
Visualizing_sentiment %>% 
    gather(sentiment, values, -date) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(y = values, x = date, fill = sentiment), stat = "identity")
```

But I wanted to have the date variable formatted in month/year format in the x-axis, so I tried to change the format of my date variable to Date class as follows:

```
lubridate::ymd('20111201')
lubridate::ymd(20111201)
lubridate::ymd(Visualizing_sentiment$date)
```

While the date variable changed in format, I am receiving an error for the graph when I ran the following:

```
Visualizing_sentiment %>% 
    gather(sentiment, values, -date) %>%
    ggplot() +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels =  "%b %Y") +
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1)) +
    geom_bar(aes(y = values, x = date, fill = sentiment), stat = "identity")
```

Ideally, I want to produce a bar graph, showing the share of negative, positive, and neutral sentiment by month/year.

[image]

Thanks to the advice below, I ran the following and it works well:

```
Visualizing_sentiment %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))%>%
  count(sentiment, date)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n, fill = sentiment))+
  geom_col() +
  #geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive" = "green", 
                               "negative" = "red", 
                               "neutral"= "black"))+
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%y")+
    facet_wrap(~ year(date))
  theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot sentiment over time you need a date column and a sentiment column. Then you can count the sentiment by date with count(sentiment, date) and then you can plot date along the x axis, n up the y axis, and fill by sentiment.

If you want stacked bar charts, remove position = "dodge" from geom_col()

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  sentiment = c("positive", "positive", "negative", "negative", "neutral", "neutral",
                "neutral", "positive", "negative", "neutral", "neutral", "negative",
                "negative", "neutral", "neutral", "positive"),
  date = c("2010-02-03", "2010-02-03", "2010-02-04", "2010-02-04", "2010-02-04", "2010-02-05",
           "2010-02-05", "2010-02-05", "2010-02-05", "2010-02-05", "2010-02-03", "2010-02-04",
           "2010-02-04", "2010-02-05", "2010-02-04", "2010-02-04")
)
data %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))%>%
  count(sentiment, date)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = n, fill = sentiment))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive" = "green", 
                               "negative" = "red", 
                               "neutral"= "black"))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y")+
  theme_bw()
```

I added a scale_x_date() for you. the %b represents Month abbreviation, and the %Y is the year. If you just wanted say '10' instead of '2010' you could go for %y.

A recommendation if doing this for multiple years, would be an extra step, and use a facet_wrap() to show each year as a separate chart. Which you could do like so:

```r
previous_plotting_code+
    facet_wrap(~ year(date))
```

the year() function will pick out the year from the date variable, courtesy of lubridate.

Comment: This is perfect and super close to what I am looking for! But would it be possible to include month/year in the x-axis? 
Currently, it only shows month, so it might be a bit confusing to see several Jan, Feb, etc in the x-axis. I have added to the post how the graph currently looks like.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer. I would recommend trying with just geom_col() in place of geom_col(position = "dodge"), and certainly try the facet_wrap(~ year(date()) for multiple years, or you'll risk creating a pretty ugly visualisation with too much info :)

Comment: This is perfect!